# TexStudio Structure Overview gets broken by a figure

Tags: floats, texstudio, structure

I have a figure in my subsubsection like this:

```
\section{Konzeption}
really interesting!

\subsection{Strukturierung}
see more details here

\subsubsection{Start-Skript}
Lorem ipsum...

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \scalebox{.8}{\input{charts/start_traffic_script}}
    \caption{start script}
    \label{fig:start_script}
\end{figure}

bla bla...

\subsubsection{Haupt-Skript}
Lorem Ipsum ...
```

Compiling and viewing the PDF works fine, but the structure on the left side in TexStudio gets broken which is quite annoying - it won't show the hierarchy correctly anymore. (Note, it's not a problem in the pdf viewer but in the latex file viewer)

[image: broken structure]

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 using TeXstudio 2.12.16.
Does someone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I suspect that is the file viewer in texstudio and not the bookmark in the pdf. So it is a texstudio problem and should be reported in their tracker.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ah I'll delete my comment then,

Comment: Yes it is, sorry for the bad wording in the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to **Options** -> **Configure TeXstudio...**,
2. check Show Advanced Options in the bottom left corner,
3. go to **Adv. Editor**,
4. under **Structure Panel** check **Keep indentation of includes in structure tree**.

[image: Check this box in the settings]