# TeXstudio Structure Tree View Messed Up with `\input`

Tags: sectioning, texstudio, structure

Sometimes I wish to use the `\input{...}` command when writing papers.
However, in TeXstudio, my editor of choice, this messes up the `Structure Tree` display on the left-hand side.
While I realise some people don't use this, I find it very helpful for quickly navigating---additionally, right-click on a section and it gives the option to add the `\ref{sec:...}`, which is helpful.

I include here an example. It doesn't compile since it needs an auxiliary file, but if it is pasted into TeXstudio, the issue is apparent. I have also included a picture showing what happens. In short, the `\input{...}` part is put on the highest tree-level.
Is this a known bug with a known fix?

Related: [Using structural commands in \newcommand - structure messed up?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83147/using-structural-commands-in-newcommand-structure-messed-up)

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\input{some_code.tex}
\subsection{Subsection 1.2}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh you mean the following subsection 1.2. Make a bug report in the texstudio issue tracker.

Comment: I actually found a solution via the `related` questions. (Often it's easier to find stuff on Stack Exchange via the "related questions" than searching directly!) I have copied this answer below (giving credit to the original poster).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since posting this, I have found the solution on another tex.SE question: [TexStudio Structure Overview gets broken by a figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/527722/81928).
While the question there is phrased in terms of being broken by a figure, it appears that the underlying issue is the `\input{...}` rather than the figure. It is perhaps for this reason that I did not come across the linked question in my research; hence I have kept this question open, in the hope that it will be easier for people in the future!

To be self-contained, and for preservation should anything happen to the linked answer, I have directly copied the answer here, due to user [Corbie](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/91928/corbie). **I claim no originality for what is below.**

---

1. Go to **Options** -> **Configure TeXstudio...**,
2. check Show Advanced Options in the bottom left corner,
3. go to **Adv. Editor**,
4. under **Structure Panel** check **Keep indentation of includes in structure tree**.

[image: Check this box in the settings]

---

**Note:** you may have to restart TeXstudio for this to take affect

Comment: Thanks, this works! For me the problem occured for a table that I imported using the `\input` command. I kept the table in a separate file since it was generated by pandas (the Python library).

Comment: @hexcoffee Glad it helped you! 